# Set width and height of ASP.NET (4.0) listbox to fit the items

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, size

I have a listbox on a page that is bound to a linqdatasource.
In the ondatabound event I am trying to make the size of the listbox on screen fit the items, to avoid having to scroll and to avoid excessive white space.

How can I do this?

```
protected void ListBox1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ListBox1.FitToItems();
}
protected void FitToItems() {
  ...?
}
```

Comment: ListBox without any CSS style applied fits itself to the longest text representation of the item. So implictly there's no horizontal scollbar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
Listbox.rows = Listbox.Items.count
```

Comment: This gives me a "*Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value*" error because `Listbox.Items.count` was 0 even though there were items returned by a SQLCommand firing on SelectedIndexChange of a nearby DDL.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the size attribute on the generated  tag.
Something like...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#<%=this.ListBox1.ClientID%>').attr('size', $('#<%=this.ListBox1.ClientID%> option').length);
});
```

using jQuery.

Or set it using  ListBox.Rows = ListBox.Items.Count  server side (not tried this myself, but I think that's what it does).